# Day theme and night theme for Python tkinter clock

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have been looking into making a clock for using Python Tkinter. I have managed to do so and would like to take it to the next level: automatic day/night theme change. I have tried using `strftime` and my own code for getting a close estimate of whether it's day or night. the code would always give me the wrong color for the numbers, but the right color for the colons.

Sometimes it would work only on this clock code but doesn't work with my full code.

Here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep, strftime
import datetime
import feedparser
import time
from itertools import cycle
dark = {1:16, 2:17, 3:18, 4:19, 5:19, 6:20, 7:20, 8:19, 9:18, 10:17, 11:16, 12:16}
#month_number : sunrise_hour
light = {1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:4, 7:4, 8:5, 9:6, 10:6, 11:7, 12:8}
root = tk.Tk()
current_theme = "not set"
d = feedparser.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/news/.rss')
post_list = cycle(d.entries)
def exitt():
    sleep(3)
    root.destroy()
def theme_updater(theme_bg, theme_fg):
    clock.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
    extra_clock.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
    label_rss.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
    end.config(fg=theme_fg, bg=theme_bg)
time1 = ''
extra_time1 = ''
clock = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri light', 150))
clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
extra_clock = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri light', 45))
extra_clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
label_rss = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri', 14))
label_rss.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
end = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", font=('bold', 18), bd=0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=lambda:exitt(), height=0, width=0)
end.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
def rssfeeds():
    post = next(post_list)
    RSSFEED = post.title
    modTXT = 'r/news Feed:  ' + RSSFEED
    label_rss.config(text=modTXT)
    root.after(8000, rssfeeds)
rssfeeds()
def tick():
 global current_theme
 global time1
 time2 = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 if time2 != time1:
  time1 = time2
  clock.config(text=time2)
 time_now = time.localtime()
 if time_now.tm_hour <= dark[time_now.tm_mon] or time_now.tm_hour < light[time_now.tm_mon]:
        if current_theme != "night":
            theme_updater("black", "white")
            current_theme = "night"
            print('Night time theme set.')
 else:
        if current_theme != "day":
            theme_updater("white", "black")
            current_theme = "day"
            print('Day time theme set.')
 clock.after(1000, tick)
def ticki():
 global extra_time1
 extra_time2 = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
 if extra_time2 != extra_time1:
  extra_time1 = extra_time2
  extra_clock.config(text=extra_time2)
 extra_clock.after(1000, ticki)
tick()
ticki()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

This is what happens on the day theme in my full code:
[image: Day theme]
And on the night theme:
[image: Night theme]

Comment: I currently have a program that has selectable themes and each theme is applied with a simple function call. I think if you set your themes up as a function you would be able to check the time of day and then also check to make sure a specific theme is not already applied. This would then allow your program to apply a theme automatically and only once per time shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the code you provided I moved some things around and update the `tick()` function to check the current time status.

By adding a tracking variable to see if we have already set a theme for the day we can prevent the program from reapplying the theme ever seconds and just apply once per day.

If you flip this line:

```
if time_now.tm_hour >= dark[time_now.tm_mon] or time_now.tm_hour < light[time_now.tm_mon]:
```

To this:

```
if time_now.tm_hour <= dark[time_now.tm_mon] or time_now.tm_hour > light[time_now.tm_mon]:
```

You can in affect test to make sure the night theme works so you don't have to wait all day.

I have also changed the `after()` statement to refresh the clock after 1 second as there is no point in updating the clock 5 times a second.

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

dark = {1:16, 2:17, 3:18, 4:19, 5:19, 6:20, 7:20, 8:19, 9:18, 10:17, 11:16, 12:16}
#month_number : sunrise_hour
light = {1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:4, 7:4, 8:5, 9:6, 10:6, 11:7, 12:8}

root = tk.Tk()
time1 = ''
clock = tk.Label(root, font=('calibri', 20, 'bold'))
clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
current_theme = "not set"

def theme_updater(theme_bg, theme_fg):
    clock.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)

def tick():
    global time1, clock, current_theme
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)

    time_now = time.localtime()
    if time_now.tm_hour >= dark[time_now.tm_mon] or time_now.tm_hour < light[time_now.tm_mon]:
        if current_theme != "night":
            theme_updater("black", "white")
            current_theme = "night"
            print('Night time theme set.')
    else:
        if current_theme != "day":
            theme_updater("white", "black")
            current_theme = "day"
            print('Day time theme set.')
    clock.after(1000, tick)

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

Based on your updated question I have reworked your code into OOP. I was unable to reproduce your error however some things look like they needed changing. For example you were using `sleep` in tkinter and that will cause your program to freeze. We can use `after` instead.

I removed the rss feed part as it was not relevant for testing.

Take a look at the below example and let me know if it helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import strftime
import time


class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.dark = {1:16, 2:17, 3:18, 4:19, 5:19, 6:20, 7:20, 8:19, 9:18, 10:17, 11:16, 12:16}
        self.light = {1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:4, 7:4, 8:5, 9:6, 10:6, 11:7, 12:8}
        self.current_theme = "not set"
        self.time1 = ''
        self.extra_time1 = ''
        self.clock = tk.Label(self, font=('calibri light', 150))
        self.clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.extra_clock = tk.Label(self, font=('calibri light', 45))
        self.extra_clock.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.label_rss = tk.Label(self, font=('calibri', 14))
        self.label_rss.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.end = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", font=('bold', 18), bd=0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=self.exitt, height=0, width=0)
        self.end.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.w, self.h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.focus_set()
        self.tick()
        self.ticki()

    def exitt(self):
        self.after(3000, self.destroy)

    def theme_updater(self, theme_bg, theme_fg):
        self.clock.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
        self.extra_clock.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
        self.label_rss.config(bg=theme_bg, fg=theme_fg)
        self.end.config(fg=theme_fg, bg=theme_bg)

    def tick(self):
        time2 = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if time2 != self.time1:
            self.time1 = time2
            self.clock.config(text=time2)
        time_now = time.localtime()
        if time_now.tm_hour >= self.dark[time_now.tm_mon] or time_now.tm_hour < self.light[time_now.tm_mon]:
            if self.current_theme != "night":
                self.theme_updater("black", "white")
                self.current_theme = "night"
                print('Night time theme set.')
        else:
            if self.current_theme != "day":
                self.theme_updater("white", "black")
                self.current_theme = "day"
                print('Day time theme set.')
        self.clock.after(1000, self.tick)

    def ticki(self):
        extra_time2 = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
        if extra_time2 != self.extra_time1:
            self.extra_time1 = extra_time2
            self.extra_clock.config(text=extra_time2)
        self.extra_clock.after(1000, self.ticki)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So in my full code, using this, the night time theme works only. Daytime theme works ok with the date and rss feed and exit buton, but the time colors are messed up the colon is black, but the numbers are white

Comment: My answer is just an example of how you would go about setting up a timed theme. You will need to chose what widgets get changed on each theme update.  That said the arguments `fg=set_txt` and `bg=set_bg` mean nothing in your example as you do not define set_text or set_bg anywhere. Keep in mind if you are using some kind of StringVar this will not change your bg or fg when that StringVar changes.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but on night theme, all widgets are the right color, and on day theme, all wigets are the right color except for the numbers on the clock. the colon is black, but the numbers are white. (this is only in my full code)

Comment: @TrooperZ most likely you are missing the config command for the clock. Only way to explain it really without seeing the code.

Comment: @TrooperZ can you provide a screen shot of your issue? or maybe some more code that has an example of the issue?

Comment: i have provided the code and picures in the original question

Comment: I took your code and ran it. I cannot reproduce your error. It works for both themes on my end. I will convert this code to a OOP style and lets see if that helps.

Comment: @TrooperZ ok I have added an updated version of your code let me know if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work again. Could it be because i am using raspbian on a RPi 3?

Comment: Well maybe there is a python version bug. What version of python are you currently using? From a code perspective I cannot see a reason why the text is not black on the day time theme.

Comment: Python 2.7.1 is my version

Comment: Do you have to use 2.7 on your RPI3 or can you update to 3.6? If you can update I would do that. That said I have also tested this code on 2.7 and it works on my end.

Comment: I have 3.5 and 2.7. I will try using 3.5 and see if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173427/discussion-between-trooper-z-and-mike-smt).