# How do I add dark and light themes to my program?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, themes, light

I've been on here before with this same code but I can't make it work properly. I'm making a to do list program for a computer science project in high school and want to add a dark mode to it. How exactly would I do that? The program is in python and im using repl.it for developing. Also, plz ignore my attempt at adding dark mode, just look at the code for the main program :)

here's the code:

```
 import tkinter
 import tkinter.messagebox
 from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
 import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
 import pickle
 import tkinter as tk

 root = tkinter.Tk()
 root.title("To-Do List")

 def add_task():
     task = entry_task.get()
     if task != "":
         listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
         entry_task.delete(0, tkinter.END)
     else:
         tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Please enter a task")

 def delete_task():
     try:
         task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
         listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
     except:
         tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Please select a task first")

 def load_tasks():
     try:
         tasks = pickle.load(open("tasks.dat", "rb"))
         listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
         for task in tasks:
             listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
     except:
         tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Cant find saved task file")

 def save_tasks():
     tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
     pickle.dump(tasks, open("tasks.dat", "wb"))

 # Dark and light modes   
 app = tk.Tk()
 app.geometry("200x400")
 app.title("Themes")

 # theme
 style = ThemedStyle(app)
 style.set_theme("scidgrey")

 # theme menu buttons 
 Def_Btn = tk.Button(app,text='Light mode')
 Def_Btn.pack()
 Themed_Btn = ttk.Button(app,text='Night mode')
 Themed_Btn.pack()

 # Scrollbar 
 Def_Scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(app)
 Def_Scrollbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
 Themed_Scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(app,orient='horizontal')
 Themed_Scrollbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')

 # Entry Widgets
 Def_Entry = tk.Entry(app)
 Def_Entry.pack()
 Themed_Entry = ttk.Entry(app)
 Themed_Entry.pack()

 # theme chooser gui
 frame_tasks = tkinter.Frame(root)
 frame_tasks.pack()

 listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(frame_tasks, height=10, width=50)
 listbox_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

 scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame_tasks)
 scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

 listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
 scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)

 entry_task = tkinter.Entry(root, width=50)
 entry_task.pack()

 button_add_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Add a task", width=48, command=add_task)
 button_add_task.pack()

 button_delete_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Delete a task", width=48, command=delete_task)
 button_delete_task.pack()

 button_load_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Load a task list", width=48, command=load_tasks)
 button_load_tasks.pack()

 button_save_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Save your task list", width=48, command=save_tasks)
 button_save_tasks.pack()


 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make a new variable on the top of your program. Depending on that variable add `background="black", foreground="white"` to all of your widgets (note some of them might not support foreground).

Comment: You could also use `ttk.Style` and create a style for each widget and use `config()` on the widget when the user selects dark mode, to change the style option to dark mode. Plus there are already some themes that look like dark mode too.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example define a `def darkmode():` function where you `.configure` all backgrounds (& and foregrounds)

Example:

```
def darkmode(): 
    Themed_Entry.configure(bg="black", fg="white")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.config` and create a couple of functions, and assign them to different buttons

For example, a light mode function that updates the window and such to a bright color scheme:

```
def light_theme():
    listbox_tasks.config(bg="white", fg="black")
    button_add_task.config(highlightbackground='white')
    button_delete_task.config(highlightbackground='white')
    button_load_tasks.config(highlightbackground='white')
    button_save_tasks.config(highlightbackground='white')
    entry_task.config(bg='white', fg='black')
```

And here is it's corresponding dark variant:

```
def dark_theme():
    color = '#1f1f1f'
    listbox_tasks.config(bg=color, fg="white")
    button_add_task.config(highlightbackground=color)
    button_delete_task.config(highlightbackground=color)
    button_load_tasks.config(highlightbackground=color)
    button_save_tasks.config(highlightbackground=color)
    entry_task.config(bg=color, fg='white')
```

The above code changes button's backgrounds and such to the hex code `#1f1f1f`, which is a dark grey color, feel free to change it if you want (change the `color` variable). the buttons in repl.it don't seem to update background color, only border color.

you can assign these functions to your buttons

```
Def_Btn = tk.Button(app, text='Light mode', command=light_theme)
Def_Btn.pack()
Themed_Btn = ttk.Button(app, text='Night mode', command=dark_theme)
Themed_Btn.pack()
```

**Note:** make sure that you **define the two functions before the buttons** (paste the code before the buttons) or else you get an error, because the functions are not yet defined

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building your app with classes. It makes things like changing custom themes much easier.

Especially if you have lots of widgets you want to configure, then it is easier to just change the attribute of a class and then just restart the GUI.

Please refer to my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71832319/18344525

Feel free to play around with the code.